# Adding rows and keeping formatting - Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I need to put together a script that will add rows in a table and keep the existing formatting from the row above. I have two separate functions that will do the same thing, in add a row and keep the existing formatting from the row above. The tables are identical but are just different locations on the spreadsheet.

For some reason the second table when i run the script it is adding the row 5 cells below where it should in row 37. I specified to start the second row in cell 33, but for some reason when I add the second row it is adding it. Anybody know what I could be doing wrong?

Any help is very much appreciated

Updated code

```
    // global 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name:"Add New Last Row", functionName:"addRow"}];
  ss.addMenu("Extra", menu);
}

function addRow() {
  var s, data, rw;
  s=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  data=s.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (rw in data) {
    if (data[rw][6]=="Condition Description :") break;
  }
  s.insertRowBefore(Number(rw));
  s.getRange(Number(rw), 4, 1, 2).merge();
  s.getRange(Number(rw), 8).setFormula("=f"+Number(rw)+"*g"+Number(rw));
}

function addFirstRow() {
    var firstRow= 15;
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lCol = sh.getLastColumn();
    var range = sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, 1, lCol);
    var formulas = range.getFormulas();
    sh.insertRowsAfter(firstRow, 1);
    sh.getRange(firstRow+1, 4, 1,2).mergeAcross();
    sh.getRange(firstRow+1, 7, 1,2).mergeAcross();
    newRange = sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, 1, lCol);
    newRange.setFormulas(formulas);
    sh.getRange(firstRow+1, 4, 1,2).mergeAcross();
    sh.getRange(firstRow+1, 7, 1,2).mergeAcross();
}


function addSecondRow() {

    var firstRow= 33;
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lCol = sh.getLastColumn();
    var range = sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, 1, lCol);
    var formulas = range.getFormulas();
    sh.insertRowsAfter(firstRow, 1);
    sh.getRange(firstRow+1, 4, 1,2).mergeAcross();
    sh.getRange(firstRow+1, 7, 1,2).mergeAcross();
    newRange = sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, 1, lCol);
    newRange.setFormulas(formulas);
        sh.getRange(firstRow+1, 4, 1,2).mergeAcross();
    sh.getRange(firstRow+1, 7, 1,2).mergeAcross();

}
```

Comment: This code works at row 33 for me, the only edit i have is the following `newRange = sh.getRange(firstRow+1, 1, 1, lCol);` note the change `+1` to firstRow. Assuming you want to add the formulas to the next row you just inserted.

Comment: Also, you can lose the two redundant mergeAcross function at the end

Comment: @JackBrown I see what I was doing wrong, thank you! One last thing when i run the script its deleting all the data in row 33. What could i do to prevent it from deleting data from the row its pulling the formatting from?

Comment: If you follow my suggestion in the first comment it shouldn't do that. However, if you update code in the question to the lastest code, I can have a quick at it to see whats going on

Comment: @JackBrown code is updated. Thanks again for looking into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should be the following:

```
function addSecondRow() {

    var firstRow= 33;
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lCol = sh.getLastColumn();
    var range = sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, 1, lCol);
    var formulas = range.getFormulas();
    sh.insertRowsAfter(firstRow, 1);
    sh.getRange(firstRow+1, 4, 1,2).mergeAcross();
    sh.getRange(firstRow+1, 7, 1,2).mergeAcross();
    newRange = sh.getRange(firstRow+1, 1, 1, lCol);  
    newRange.setFormulas(formulas);

}
```

Like I mentioned in my comment, this is incorrect a syntax

```
newRange = sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, 1, lCol);
```

since it will select the row above the one you just inserted.
the correct way to select the row you just added is:

```
newRange = sh.getRange(firstRow+1, 1, 1, lCol);
```